# How can I get repeatable field values of a Liferay Dynamic Data List via API

Tags: field, liferay-6, ddl

I try to make a service for reading from Liferay 6.2 DDL.

Here is DDL structure :

```
<root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US">
    <dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="text" localizable="false" name="Course_ID" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="true" showLabel="true" type="text" width="medium">
        <dynamic-element dataType="boolean" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="Active" readOnly="false" repeatable="true" required="false" showLabel="true" type="checkbox" width="">
            <dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" multiple="false" name="Language" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="select" width="">
                <dynamic-element name="option22436" type="option" value="en">
                    <meta-data locale="en_US">
                        <entry name="label">
                            <![CDATA[English]]>
                        </entry>
                    </meta-data>
                </dynamic-element>
                <dynamic-element name="option22437" type="option" value="fr">
                    <meta-data locale="en_US">
                        <entry name="label">
                            <![CDATA[French]]>
                        </entry>
                    </meta-data>
                </dynamic-element>
                <dynamic-element name="option22438" type="option" value="de">
                    <meta-data locale="en_US">
                        <entry name="label">
                            <![CDATA[Deutsch]]>
                        </entry>
                    </meta-data>
                </dynamic-element>
                <meta-data locale="en_US">
                    <entry name="label">
                        <![CDATA[Language]]>
                    </entry>
                    <entry name="predefinedValue">
                        <![CDATA[[""]]]>
                    </entry>
                    <entry name="tip">
                        <![CDATA[]]>
                    </entry>
                </meta-data>
            </dynamic-element>
            <dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="Guest_URL" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="text" width="small">
                <meta-data locale="en_US">
                    <entry name="label">
                        <![CDATA[Guest URL]]>
                    </entry>
                    <entry name="predefinedValue">
                        <![CDATA[]]>
                    </entry>
                    <entry name="tip">
                        <![CDATA[]]>
                    </entry>
                </meta-data>
            </dynamic-element>
            <dynamic-element dataType="string" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="Registered_URL" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="text" width="small">
                <meta-data locale="en_US">
                    <entry name="label">
                        <![CDATA[Registered URL]]>
                    </entry>
                    <entry name="predefinedValue">
                        <![CDATA[]]>
                    </entry>
                    <entry name="tip">
                        <![CDATA[]]>
                    </entry>
                </meta-data>
            </dynamic-element>
            <meta-data locale="en_US">
                <entry name="label">
                    <![CDATA[Active]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="predefinedValue">
                    <![CDATA[true]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="tip">
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </entry>
            </meta-data>
        </dynamic-element>
        <dynamic-element dataType="document-library" fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="Documents_and_Media8331" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-documentlibrary" width="">
            <meta-data locale="en_US">
                <entry name="label">
                    <![CDATA[Documents and Media]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="predefinedValue">
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </entry>
                <entry name="tip">
                    <![CDATA[]]>
                </entry>
            </meta-data>
        </dynamic-element>
        <meta-data locale="en_US">
            <entry name="label">
                <![CDATA[Course ID]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="predefinedValue">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
            <entry name="tip">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </entry>
        </meta-data>
    </dynamic-element>
</root>
```

As you can see I have a repeatable checkbox container, who have 3 more element inside
[structure view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikBwA.jpg)

I can get and iterate records list, but no idea how can I get a list with all checkboxes and iterate for their elements inside

```
DynamicQuery getRecordsetIdQuery = DDLRecordSetLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery()
            .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.distinct(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("recordSetId")))
            .add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.ilike("name", courseSetName));

    DynamicQuery getDdlRecordListQuery = DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery()
            .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("recordSetId").in(getRecordsetIdQuery));

    JSONArray courseList = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();

    List ddlRecordList = DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(getDdlRecordListQuery);
    if (ddlRecordList != null && ddlRecordList.size() > 0) {
        int ddlRecordListSize = ddlRecordList.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < ddlRecordListSize; i++) {
            DDLRecord ddlRec = (DDLRecord) ddlRecordList.get(i);
            Field active = ddlRec.getField("Active");
```

...

Do you can help me with some ideas please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three fields. solution for how to get repeated Field in portlet.

1.LanguageName (Parent and Repeated Field) 
 2. DocumentLinkLabel (Repeated Field)
 3. DocumentLink (Child Field)

```
for (JournalArticle journalArticle : journalArticleList) {
    Document docxml;
    try {
        docxml = SAXReaderUtil.read(journalArticle.getContent());
        Node root = docxml.getRootElement();
        List<Node> languageList = root.selectNodes("/root/dynamic- 
        element[@name='LanguageName']");    

        for (int i = 0; i < languageList.size(); i++)
        {
            Node languageNode = languageList.get(i);
            String languageName =languageNode.selectNodes("/root/dynamic- 
            element[@name='LanguageName']/dynamic-content[@language- 
            id='en_US']").get(i).getText();
            System.out.println("language Name : "+ languageName);

             List<Node> documentLinkLabelList =languageNode.selectNodes("dynamic-element[@name='DocumentLinkLabel']/dynamic-element[@name='DocumentLink']");
             for (int j = 0; j < documentLinkLabelList.size(); j++) {
                 Node languageNode1 = documentLinkLabelList.get(j);
                 String documentLinkName =languageNode.selectNodes("dynamic- 
                 element[@name='DocumentLinkLabel']/dynamic-content[@language-id='en_US']").get(j).getText();
                 System.out.println(" document Link Lable Name : "+ documentLinkName);
                 String linkNameList=languageNode1.selectNodes("//dynamic- 
                 element[@name='LanguageName']["+(i+1)+"]/dynamic- 
                 element[@name='DocumentLinkLabel']/dynamic-element[@name='DocumentLink']/dynamic-content[@language-id='en_US']").get(j).getText();
                 System.out.println(" linkNameList : "+ linkNameList);
             }
        }
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly access `DDList` content in code. You have to get the xml of the record from the database and use `SAXParserUtil` and `XPath` expressions to read the values.

Comment: Can you provide some example how-to. I can't get XML with fields value from record. ddlRec.toXmlString() return me only unusual information

Comment: I toоk it with 

`long storageId = ddlRec.getDDMStorageId();
DDMContent ddmContent = DDMContentLocalServiceUtil.getContent(storageId);
String ddmXml = ddmContent.getXml();`

but this is so UGLY XML for mine purpose, any way